# Swift Generics and Protocols not working on UIKit [possible bug]

Tags: swift, generics, delegates, protocols

**TL;DR -> scroll to bottom**

In trying to tag Apple on the Protocol-Oriented Programming with Swift, I stumbled upon the following problem while trying to implement a delegation pattern between classes.

I'll start with this example:

```
protocol PhotoHandlerParent {}

class UIViewController {}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, PhotoHandlerParent {}

class PhotoHandler: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    weak var delegate: PhotoHandlerParent
}
```

So far, so good. An instance of `MyViewController` would be happily assigned as `PhotoHandler`'s delegate. But say I not only wanted the delegate object to conform to `PhotoHandlerParent`, but also be of class `UIViewController`. In this particular example, so that the `PhotoHandler` could present and dismiss an `UIImagePickerController` on behalf of its parent view controller. Much like:

```
protocol PhotoHandlerParent {}

class UIViewController {}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, PhotoHandlerParent {}

class PhotoHandler: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    weak var delegate: UIViewController, PhotoHandlerParent
}
```

Unfortunetely, the code above doesn't work on Swift. On the other hand though, Swift does have Generics, that may help in this case. Thus one might try:

```
protocol PhotoHandlerParent {}

class UIViewController {}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, PhotoHandlerParent {}

class PhotoHandler<Parent where Parent: UIViewController, Parent: PhotoHandlerParent>: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    weak var delegate: Parent
}
```

Now interestingly enough, an instance of `MyViewController` would go back to be happily assigned as `PhotoHandler`'s delegate. No compile error, no runtime error. But...

**TL;DR: The problem**

Running the [sample code](https://github.com/BellAppLab/Protocols) for this question, it's possible to see that an instance of a class declared with Generics and set as a `UIImagePickerController`'s delegate is never called by it. An instance of an object declared **without** generics is called by the `UIImagePickerController`.

My best assumption is that the compiler doesn't complain because it can verify that `PhotoHandler` conforms to `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`. However, at runtime, the `PhotoHandler` instance is actually a `PhotoHandler<MyViewController>` instance, thus somehow interfering with the `UIImagePickerController`'s ability to identify that its delegate actually implements its protocol.

Or am I missing something maybe?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct behavior from the documentation point of view, because:

> Method in a generic class cannot be represented in Objective-C

---

*Reply to @Bell App Lab* comment:

Open [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID173) and scroll down to *Lightweight Generics*. Here's note:

> Aside from than these Foundation collection classes, Objective-C
>   lightweight generics are ignored by Swift. Any other types using
>   lightweight generics are imported into Swift as if they were
>   unparameterized.

It basically says that generics (ObjC -> Swift) are imported only for Foundation collection classes and rest is ignored - IOW imported as if they are unparameterized.

Maybe we can expect some improvement in this area in the future, but I doubt it.

Comment: "Cannot be represented in Objective-C" doesn't make it correct. Just means the bridge between the languages is broken. Conversely, how would Swift handle this: `@property (nonatomic, weak) UIViewController<PhotoHandlerParent> *parent;`?

Comment: @BellAppLab did edit my answer to make it clearer also with link to a page where ObjC lightweight generics are handled in Swift.