# Swift: typealias for composition type

Tags: objective-c, swift

In Objective-C, I could declare a class a subclass and conform to a protocol:

```
@interface SubClass : ParentClass<OneProtocol>
```

When bridged to Swift 1.x, `SubClass` becomes

```
class SubClass : ParentClass, OneProtocol
```

I find it difficult to use this kind of composite type. For example, without using generics, how to say a function returns an instance of a `ParentClass` that conforms to `OneProtocol`?

I know if it is two protocols, we can use `protocol<OneProtocol, TwoProtocol>`. But here one of them is class.

Ideally there is a syntax to declare this as a typealias. But if it is not possible, the last resort is to compose in Objective-C, and bridge the composition to Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a job for Swift's Generics. But apparently [it is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31187540/1603482) to achieve the same Obj-C behaviour in Swift.