# How to make a protocol extension constraint to two types in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a protocol and its corresponding extension that looks something like this:

```
import Foundation


protocol HelpActionManageable {
    typealias ItemType : UIViewController,HelpViewControllerDelegate
    var viewController : ItemType {
        get
    }
}

extension HelpActionManageable  {
    func presentHelpViewController() {
        let helpViewController = HelpViewController(nibName: HelpViewController.nibName(), bundle: nil)
        viewController.presentViewController(helpViewController, animated: true, completion:nil)
        helpViewController.delegate = viewController
    }
    func dismissSuccessfulHelpViewController(helpViewController:HelpViewController) {
        helpViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { () -> Void  in
            self.viewController.showAlertControllerWithTitle(GlobalConstants.Strings.SUCCESS, message: GlobalConstants.Strings.VALUABLE_FEEDBACK, actions: [], dismissingActionTitle: GlobalConstants.Strings.OK, dismissBlock: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

So, in a random view controller that confirms to this protocol, I am doing something like this:

```
class RandomViewController : UIViewController, HelpViewControllerDelegate,HelpActionManageable {
    //HelpViewControllerDelegate methods...
    var viewController : RandomViewController {
        return self
    }
}
```

This works fine, but it would be very neat if the extension `HelpActionManageable` methods are available for only types that confirm to `UIViewController` AND `HelpViewControllerDelegate`.

Something like this:

```
extension HelpActionManageable where Self == ItemType
```

This doesn't work. How can I achieve this in Swift?

Comment: I don't think Swift supports this yet. [See](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31187540/swift-generics-and-protocols-not-working-on-uikit-possible-bug)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is supported now.

```
extension HelpActionManageable where Self == ItemType  {
}
```

or

```
extension HelpActionManageable where Self: ItemType  {
}
```

works for me.